# Disproportioned contingency table

Tags: skewness, contingency-tables

I have a database of clients, some of which have gotten a special pill - and the rest have not gotten the special pill. Afterwards I measure if the clients starts exercising. My contingency table looks like this:

```
     Pill   No pill
Yes  46      4840
No   16      3694
```

'Yes' are for the clients that started to exercise, and 'No' for those who did not.
Now, the percentage of clients recieving the pill is very, very small, as you can see. The pill is extremely expensive. So the 'No pill' clients are basically just the rest of my client database. Will this be a problem when doing a chi square test for independence? I want to see if the clients getting the pill exercise more.

The normal assumptions/restrictions on a 2x2 table when performing this test are:

- Each observation is independent of all the others (i.e., one observation per subject)
- "No more than 20% of the expected counts are less than 5 and all individual expected     counts are 1 or greater" (Yates, Moore & McCabe, 1999, p. 734).

Comment: You might find the log-likelihood ratio test behaves better than a chi-squared test for small counts.  (In this case both seem to agree there's a significant difference.)

Comment: @conjugateprior : can you explain further why exactly the chi square test for independence is ill behaved? And would you not need to specify a distribution to do a log-likelihood ratio test?

Comment: It can be ill-behaved in the sense that the test statistic converges relatively slowly to the chi-squared distribution that the test assumes it has.  Minus twice the log likelihood ratio (against the independence model) converges faster. Here's a [readable discussion](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.5962) to the same distribution.

Comment: So when does any statistic based on a 2x2 contingency table converge?
And what distribution do you mean, exactly, when doing the llr-test? Bernoulli distribution?

Comment: When does any statistic converge to its asymptotic distribution? Obviously, it depends.  That's the point.  What distribution do I mean exactly when doing the llr test? I mean the chi-squared distribution (there was a typo in my comment - it should have read 'converges faster to the same distribution').  Maybe also read the first part of the paper I linked to?  It answers these questions.

Comment: Exactly, so that is my question, what does it depend on?
Also, when you do a llr test you must use some distribution to calculate the log likelihood, correct? So I am asking what distribution you used. Also, my original question is unanswered: Is a disproportioned contigency table as my own a problem?

Comment: Every single model or test we have discussed assumes Binomial sampling of one form or another; the issue is just what the parameters of those Binomials are. It's all discussed in the paper.  Try reading it.  Or if that's too arduous, here are two web pages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test (the paper I suggested is footnote 6).

Comment: fwiw The answer to your question is: 'possibly, but probably not'. I've been trying to express the reasoning behind that response, but I see you're not interested so I'll stop.

Comment: I do apologize if I came across as not interested. I have already read the article, and it is not too ardous. I understand the point you are trying to make about converging slower. But I fail to see how this translates to my question, as I have plenty of observations, as you see in my contingency table. I am trying to get a better understanding of how you deduce your 'possibly, but probably not'...

Comment: Try  logistic regression and confidence interval for the logodds-ratio based on likelihood profiling?