# How does Chisq.test() calculate degrees of freedom from two vectors as opposed to a matrix?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I'm confused about the way chisq.test() is handling a very simple table from an exercise where I asked students to "sample" a bag of M&Ms and compare their scope to the pooled samples from their lab mates, to wit:

```
> mm1<-data.frame(
+     color = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "brown"),
+     mySample = c(9,10,9,15,13,7),
+     myTable = c(26,28,34,44,44,18))
> chisq.test(mm1$mySample,mm1$myTable)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  mm1$mySample and mm1$myTable
X-squared = 18, df = 16, p-value = 0.3239

Warning message:
In chisq.test(mm1$mySample, mm1$myTable) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
> chisq.test(mm1[,2:3])

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  mm1[, 2:3]
X-squared = 0.67269, df = 5, p-value = 0.9844
```

The second version is what I'd expect (5 d.f.), but why is the first one failing and where is it coming up with 16 d.f.? I don't think any of my expected values should be less then 5 for this set, so I don't think that error reflects the small-cell issue that's discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81483/warning-in-r-chi-squared-approximation-may-be-incorrect?newreg=c3a9b7c4c9ce45b6ab395886965dd53a). Is.atomic() and is.numeric() on mm1\$mySample and mm1\$myTable all evaluate to TRUE, so what's the difference between passing them as an X and Y and passing them as a matrix?

Comment: The second thing one does in `R`, after trying to read the help page (which often is terse and opaque), is to examine the code.  The key line is `x <- table(x, y)` (line 25 of the code).  Take a look at what that gives when `x` is `mySample` and `y` is `myTable`.

Comment: This is flagged as off-topic. But this is not really a Q about how to use R (which *is* off-topic), but about understanding what it does, which is on-topic

Comment: "to the pooled samples from their lab makes" (presumably you mean *lab mates* there) -- I hope those pooled samples exclude their own data.

Comment: Link following @whuber's comment for various ways to check source code in R: (https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/1834244) (several different options offered over the different answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: the second version works as it treats the input data as though they were a contingency table.

From `help(chisq.test)`

> If x is a matrix with at least two rows and columns, it is taken as a two-dimensional contingency table: the entries of x must be non-negative integers.

The "two vector" version (your first bit of code) is treating the input in a different fashion from what you expect. This treats each row like a single observation (e.g. there are five observations with the observed values 7, 9, 10, 13, and 15) and then comparing those responses with the second vector.

This is a little bit more opaque in the help file: see added emphasis below.

> Otherwise, x and y must be vectors or factors of the same length; cases with missing values are removed, the objects are coerced to factors, **and the contingency table is computed from these**

You can see how these data are being treated in the output below:

### Code example of what two vector analysis is doing

```
mm1 <- data.frame(
         color = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "brown"),
         mySample = c(9,10,9,15,13,7),
         myTable = c(26,28,34,44,44,18))

check_chisq <- chisq.test(mm1$mySample, mm1$myTable)
```

Have a look at this stored object and you will see the "observed" data being interrogated:

```
check_chisq$observed

            mm1$myTable
mm1$mySample 18 26 28 34 44
          7   1  0  0  0  0
          9   0  1  0  1  0
         10   0  0  1  0  0
         13   0  0  0  0  1
         15   0  0  0  0  1
```

Hence this is being treated as a 5x5 table: which then gives 16 d.f. but as you can see is not what you want in this example.

Comment: Thanks, @james, this is exactly the help I needed. I'm going to use this exchange as an example for the class!