# Chi squared test with reasonable sample size results in R warning

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I am trying to identify whether a specific sample is likely coming from a certain data population using the `chi squared` test. I use R to do the calculation and my data look as follows:

```
test_data = structure(c(1527, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 834), .Dim = c(3L, 3L
), .Dimnames = list(c("group1", "group2", "group3"), c("cat1", 
"cat2", "cat3")))

pop_data = structure(c(0.520621281885302, 0.0393739768609051, 0.00151193550372226, 
0.0265310369198176, 0.0358531412498173, 0.0160897048601235, 0.00730664851935212, 
0.00000623849183296829, 0.352706035709127), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("group1", "group2", "group3"), c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3"
    )))

> test_data
       cat1 cat2 cat3
group1 1527    0    0
group2    0   17    0
group3    0    0  834


> pop_data
              cat1       cat2           cat3
group1 0.520621282 0.02653104 0.007306648519
group2 0.039373977 0.03585314 0.000006238492
group3 0.001511936 0.01608970 0.352706035709

> chisq.test(test_data, p = pop_data)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  test_data
X-squared = 4756, df = 4, p-value < 0.00000000000000022

Warning message:
In chisq.test(test_data, p = pop_data) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

I had a look to see plausible reasons for this warning and I found this answer ([Warning in R - Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81483/warning-in-r-chi-squared-approximation-may-be-incorrect)) but I don't think that my test data are that small in terms of sample size.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This warning is due to an error by Pearson, the inventor of the test, who wrongly estimated that P-values would not be accurate were an expected cell frequency be less than 5.  See [this](https://www.zotero.org/groups/2199991/feh/tags/fishers-exact-test/library).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. Would you simply ignore this warning or do some other type of test ?

Comment: I would ignore it myself.  And don't use the continuity correction, which makes the Pearson test less accurate in an attempt to mimic the inaccurate Fisher's exact test.

Comment: +1.  But a software warning is a warning and sometimes it *should* be heeded.  The most important time to do that is *when you don't understand it.*  Otherwise, ignoring it is (at best) reckless and (at worst) leading you into error.  Fortunately, the `chisq.test` function makes it easy to assess whether to be concerned: simply rerun it with the argument `simulate.p.value = TRUE`.  If the p-value is still acceptably low, things should be okay.  In this instance, the p-value will be tiny (how tiny depends on the length of the simulation).

Comment: May I ask for some guidance as to what is achieved by the simulate.p.value part? I read that it does monte carlo simulation but I don't really get it...

Comment: @User2321, the reported p-value doesn't rely on the assumption that the expected values are sufficiently large.

Comment: The simulation is a Monte-Carlo estimate of the null sampling distribution.  It thereby avoids using the chi-squared approximation to that distribution, at a cost of considerably more computation and yielding a p-value that, although accurate, is imprecise.  It can be made more precise by increasing the length of the simulation.

Answer (score 10):

As a supplement to the answer by @Frank Harrell, here are the observed and expected frequencies and so-called Pearson residuals, (observed $-$ expected) / sqrt(expected). The name of the latter is generous to Pearson, but honours the fact that the chi-square statistic can be regarded as the sum of such residuals squared.

```
    +----------------------------------+
  1 |  1527.000   1238.037      8.212  |
  2 |     0.000     93.631     -9.676  |
  3 |     0.000      3.595     -1.896  |
  4 |     0.000     63.091     -7.943  |
  5 |    17.000     85.259     -7.392  |
  6 |     0.000     38.261     -6.186  |
  7 |     0.000     17.375     -4.168  |
  8 |     0.000      0.015     -0.122  |
  9 |   834.000    838.735     -0.163  |
    +----------------------------------+
```

In practical terms the chi-square test rejects the null overwhelmingly, but the warning presumably arises from one extremely low expected frequency and one moderately low expected frequency. The pattern of the residuals should be as or more instructive than the P-value.